# Class declaration and definitions

Tags: c++, class, header-files

Here is my Class code:

```
class LibItem
{
public:
    virtual void PrintDetails() = 0;
    void setDetails(string setItemTitle, string setItemAuthor, string setItemReleaseDate, string setItemCopyright, string setItemGenre, string setItemStatus)
    {
        Title = setItemTitle;
        Author = setItemAuthor;
        ReleaseDate = setItemReleaseDate;
        Copyright = setItemCopyright;
        Genre = setItemGenre;
        Status = setItemStatus;
    }
    void setTitle(string TitleName)
    {
        Title = TitleName;
    }
    string getTitle()
    {
        return Title;
    }
    void setReleaseDate(string date)
    {
        ReleaseDate = date;
    }
    string getReleaseDate()
    {
        return ReleaseDate;
    }
    void setAuthor(string AuthorName)
    {
        Author = AuthorName;
    }
    string getAuthor()
    {
        return Author;
    }
    void setCopyright(string CopyrightDetails)
    {
        Copyright = CopyrightDetails;
    }
    string getCopyright()
    {
        return Copyright;
    }
    void setGenre(string GenreDetails)
    {
        Genre = GenreDetails;
    }
    string getGenre()
    {
        return Genre;
    }
    void setStatus(string StatusDetails)
    {
        Status = StatusDetails;
    }
    string getStatus()
    {
        return Status;
    }
private:
    string Title;
    string ReleaseDate;
    string Author;
    string Copyright;
    string Genre;
    string Status;
};
```

I am wanting to place this into a .h file and a .cpp file.
Is the below code correct?

LibItem.cpp:

```
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------

#pragma hdrstop

#include "LibItem.h"

virtual void LibItem::PrintDetails() = 0;
void LibItem::setDetails(string setItemTitle, string setItemAuthor, string setItemReleaseDate, string setItemCopyright, string setItemGenre, string setItemStatus)
{
Title = setItemTitle;
Author = setItemAuthor;
ReleaseDate = setItemReleaseDate;
Copyright = setItemCopyright;
Genre = setItemGenre;
Status = setItemStatus;
}
void LibItem::setTitle(string TitleName)
{
Title = TitleName;
}
string LibItem::getTitle()
{
return Title;
}
void LibItem::setReleaseDate(string date)
{
ReleaseDate = date;
}
string LibItem::getReleaseDate()
{
return ReleaseDate;
}
void LibItem::setAuthor(string AuthorName)
{
Author = AuthorName;
}
string LibItem::getAuthor()
{
return Author;
}
void LibItem::setCopyright(string CopyrightDetails)
{
Copyright = CopyrightDetails;
}
string LibItem::getCopyright()
{
return Copyright;
}
void LibItem::setGenre(string GenreDetails)
{
Genre = GenreDetails;
}
string LibItem::getGenre()
{
return Genre;
}
void LibItem::setStatus(string StatusDetails)
{
Status = StatusDetails;
}
string LibItem::getStatus()
{
return Status;
}
};

//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
#pragma package(smart_init)
```

LibItem.h

```
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------

#ifndef LibItemH
#define LibItemH

class LibItem
{
public:
    virtual void PrintDetails();
    void setDetails(string, string, string, string, string, string);
    void setTitle(string);
    void setReleaseDate(string);
    string getReleaseDate();
    void setAuthor(string);
    string getAuthor();
    void setCopyright(string);
    string getCopyright();
    void setGenre(string);
    string getGenre();
    void setStatus(string);
    string getStatus();
private:
    string Title;
    string ReleaseDate;
    string Author;
    string Copyright;
    string Genre;
    string Status;
};


//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
#endif
```

Next, if I am wanting to use this .h and .cpp file in a main function, what is the code needed to be able to do this? What are the include statements needed?

Comment: Why don't you compile it ? By the way, pure virtual function should be inside the class body itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not correct:

```
virtual void LibItem::PrintDetails() = 0;
```

The `=0` should be inside the class definition (in the header).

To use the class, you need to `#include "LibItem.h"`.

Also, in the header:

```
#include <string>
```

and replace occurences of `string` with `std::string`.

`string` parameters should be passed by reference:

```
void setReleaseDate(const string& date)
```

instead of

```
void setReleaseDate(string date)
```

Comment: replace occurences of string with std::string - is this in the LibItem.h, LibItem.cpp or the .cpp file that is including the LibItem.h?

Comment: Also, for the 'void setReleaseDate(const string& date)', do I do this for the situations in LibItem.h?

Comment: @DarrylJanecek again, everywhere.

Comment: So the 'void setReleaseDate(string date)' situations should be: void setReleaseDate(const std::string& date)?

Comment: @DarrylJanecek yes. When you return, you don't use a reference though: `string getReleaseDate();` becomes `std::string getReleaseDate();`

Comment: You should also make all your get methods const, as they presumably shouldn't alter the object

Comment: @Luchian Grigore: I have updated my question. Can you please have a look?

Comment: @DarrylJanecek No! That's a completely different question.